# Software for visualizing arbitrary part of process memory content in real-time

Tags: debugging, image-processing, process, visualization, utility

In my practice I faced with the task - visualize some process memory content in real time. The main idea is read arbitrary part of remote process memory, represent it as image, and show in a separate window, then repeat these action with some interval, and in result get dynamic visualization of memory content. For example, it will be useful for view framebuffers/textures that located in process memory. Do exists any tools/software for this purpose? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I did not find any utilities, and so I created my own tool.

This is [mem2pix](https://github.com/SNMetamorph/mem2pix), program which allows to real-time visualizing some part of remote process memory, supports many pixel format type. Currently works on both Windows and Linux.